# What is the name of the category of these types of problems in probability and/or statistics?

Tags: probability

```
We roll a symmetric dice until we get one or five.     
Compute the probability that    
(a) we will make k rolls (k>=1),    
(b) we will make an odd number of rolls,    
(c) we will make at least 3 rolls.
```

These types of problems involve Infinite sample space (countable or uncountable).

I am not being able to find these types of problems in my Probability-book.

What is the name of the category of these types of problems in probability and/or statistics?

What should be the name of the topic?

Is it "Counting Technique"?

Answer (score 0):

These seem to be problems that use the geometric distribution, along with possibly a bit of infinite series in question (b).  I don't think there is a special name given to them.

I think "counting technique" refers to problems that make use of $_nP_r$ and $_nC_r$.